# How do I replicate my .htaccess functionality in NGINX

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, nginx

I have the below `.htaccess` file in apache that redirects all request to `app/index.php` with or without a `GET` parameter. I just installed NGINX and my application won't run.
Can anyone assist in replicating same functionality in NGINX? Thanks.

```
RewriteEngine on    

Options -Indexes

RewriteRule    ^$ app/ [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ app/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [rewrite module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html). Something like this should do it:

```
location / {
  autoindex off;

  rewrite ^/$ app/ last;
  if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ app/index.php?url=$1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Use try files

There is no need to use the rewrite module for most of that config.

The apache rewrite rules mean:

- `RewriteRule    ^$ app/ [L]`          - send the url / to the app dir
- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` - if the request is not a dir
- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` - if the request is not a file
- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l` - if the request is not a symlink
- Then send the request to `app/index.php?url=$1`

In nginx the equivalent is:

```
# No automatic directory listings
autoindex off;

# Send the root url to the app dir
index index.php;
rewrite ^/$ app/ last;

# check if the url matches a file, directory and if not send to app/index.php
try_files $uri $uri/ app/index.php?url=$uri;
```

The check for a symlink is superfluous since a symlink is also a file or directory.